# Insert record Many to Many relation in laravel at same time

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I have three tables users,roles and role_user I want to insert record on that tables with minimum query using eloquent. My current code of insertation

```
User::create([
        'name' => 'admin',
        'email' => 'admin@test.pk',
        'password' => bcrypt('admin123'),
    ]);

    //create default roles while installation of application
    $roles = array(
        array('name' => 'admin', 'display_name' => 'Administrator User', 'description' => 'system admin user'),
        array('name' => 'registered', 'display_name' => 'Registered User', 'description' => 'free user')
    );
    foreach ($roles as $key => $role)
    {
        Role::create($role);
    }

    //relation between users and roles

    User::find(1)->roles()->attach(1);
```

In above code i am creating a user then creating two roles then inserting record in `pivot table(role_user)`. I  want to know is there any otherway that i insert the record on these table at same time with one eloquent query Or there is anyother better way?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not possible to insert rows in more than one table at the same time.

Best what I can think of is that:

```
$user = User::create([
            'name'     => 'admin',
            'email'    => 'admin@test.pk',
            'password' => bcrypt('admin123'),
        ]);

        //create default roles while installation of application
        $roles = [
            ['name' => 'admin', 'display_name' => 'Administrator User', 'description' => 'system admin user'],
            ['name' => 'registered', 'display_name' => 'Registered User', 'description' => 'free user']
        ];
        Role::insert($roles);

        //relation between users and roles
        $user->roles()->attach(1);
```

With this example You save two queries:

1. Laravel calls only one `insert` query, instead of two when inserting roles;
2. Laravel does not select `User` from database - using variable instead;